# Django base template files

Tags: django, django-templates

I would like to ask a question about django base templates. How do they exactly work..What do I mean.

I have a base file that lets say has a static conten and a block content that changes in templates that extend the base file.

base.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="side-nav">
            <!--static content here-->
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            {% block "content"%} {%endblock%}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have three templates that extend base.html, e.g t1.html, t2.html and t3.html. All of them have some dom elements that are edited by the main.js file importedn in base.html. My question is the following. Does it load all the page its time i render a template and thus main.js is run again or does it only render the "dynamic" content of the base file? Will the code of main.js run everytime I load a template that extends base.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have to understand a basic difference:

**Rendering in done on the Server Side**

**JavaScript works on Clent side**.

So if JS is sent again to Client side than it will definitely run again

You can read more about Templates in Django here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/templates/

Comment: Yes I know that, but I don't know why I had the impression that Django only fills the "blanks" that is, only renders the different "block" pieces of the template and not all the template from the beggining (including reloading javascript files)

Comment: Hope,, you doubts are clear now... Templates inheritance work like normal Class inheritance,, A child template will have all properties (i.e. HTML) of parent template.. and {% block %} can be over-ridden in child template.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Django put together all templates at first. After that completed page will be send to browser. Your javascript code run in browser with full page.